# iOS - How do I create a read and write stream to a network socket?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios

I am new to iOS development. I am attempting to create a read and write stream. I am using the CFNetworking programming guide's examples to try and get something working.

I am trying to schedule the read stream on the run loop to work around the issue of the streams blocking. Right away I have run into issues. How can I create a CFHost object using CFHhostCreateWithAddress? Here is what I have so far:

```
NSString *address = @"irc.ubuntu.net";
CFDataRef addressDataRef = (CFDataRef)[address dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

CFHostRef host = CFHostCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, addressDataRef);

//Create Read and Write Stream
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, 8008, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

The second line bombs. Can someone please tell me how to create a CFHostRef?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFHostRef/Reference/reference.html) states that the second argument to CFHostCreateWithAddress() must be "A CFDataRef object containing a sockaddr structure for the address of the host. This value must not be NULL."

You're passing a CFDataRef representing "irc.ubuntu.net", which is by no means a sockaddr struct.

Use CFHostCreateWithName:

```
CFHostRef CFHostCreateWithName (
   CFAllocatorRef allocator,
   CFStringRef hostname
);
```

As you probably know, you can cast an NSString * to CFStringRef, or create a constant CFStringRef with the macro CFSTR().

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSData *)dataForIPAddress:(NSString *)address {
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
  hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_protocol = 0;
  int errorStatus = getaddrinfo([address cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, &hints, &result);
  if (errorStatus != 0) return nil;
  CFDataRef addressRef = CFDataCreate(NULL, (UInt8 *)result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
  if (addressRef == nil) return nil;
  freeaddrinfo(result);
  return [(NSData *)addressRef autorelease];
}
```